# (Angular) Why would you want multiple instances of the same service?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I might be missing something, and people usually ask "How to" not "Why to" whenever I google it

But what's the point of actually creating multiple instances of the same service where each instance has the same functions, same variables?

Comment: With the depenency injection mechanism, we are not creating multiple instances, the injector will look for the available instance and inject it into the component.

Comment: I need a bit more clarity on your question before I put an answer. Do you want to know "In what circumstances we would like to create multiple instances of the same service  (which does not happen in the case of Angular in general)"  . ??? In general, there is a single instance of service shared by the application, although there are case where we get multiple instances of same service in Angular. So, can you be more clear with your question please ? I'll put an answer accordingly

Comment: You've put it perfectly, the question in other words: "In what circumstances we would like to create multiple instances of the same service" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hold state.

Imagine you have an application, which has multiple tabs. Let's say they display car information, so each tab has a different car. You provide service in "root tab" component, so instance of that service will be available to all sub-components/services within that that tab, and not outside. This way you write service that stores data of one car, which reduces service complexity.

Small example

```
@Injectable()
export class CarService {
  color = '';
}
```

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [CarService]
})
export class TabComponent {
  constructor(private car: CarService) {}
  getColor() { return this.car.color }
}
```

This way you can have

```
TabComponent
  getColor() -> red
TabComponent
  getColor() -> blue
TabComponent
  getColor() -> black
```

Comment: I think I get it, thanks for the brief explanation